# Express mathematical infinity in C#

Tags: c#, math, infinite-value

Is it possible to express (mathematical) infinity, positive or negative, in C#?  If so, how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

double.PositiveInfinity

double.NegativeInfinity

```
float zero = 0;

float positive = 1 / zero;
Console.WriteLine(positive);    // Outputs "Infinity"

float negative = -1 / zero;
Console.WriteLine(negative);    // Outputs "-Infinity"
```

Comment: why didn't you just do float positive = 1/0;? why the extra step

Comment: Becuase the compiler will detect the divide by zero and stop compilation.

Comment: @Jaimal: That's because the compiler treats `1/0` as integer division. Using `1/0f` or `1/0.0` would work.

Answer (score 44):

Use the `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity` constants:

```
double positive = double.PositiveInfinity;
double negative = double.NegativeInfinity;
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, check constants values of types `float` and `double`, like:
`float.PositiveInfinity`
`float.NegativeInfinity`
Those values are compliant with IEEE-754, so you might want to check out how this works exactly, so you will be aware, when and how you can get those values while making calculations. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Answer (score 5):

```
public const double NegativeInfinity = -1.0 / 0.0;
public const double PositiveInfinity = 1.0 / 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

look this (just return Positive-infinity ∞)

> Remarks :
>
> The value of this constant is the result of dividing a positive number
>   by zero. **This constant is returned when the result of an operation is
>   greater than MaxValue.** Use IsPositiveInfinity to determine whether a
>   value evaluates to positive infinity.

So this will equal Infinity.

```
Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity plus 10.0 equals {0}.", (Double.PositiveInfinity + 10.0).ToString());
```

and now for negative is

> **This constant is returned when the result of an operation is less than MinValue.**

so this will equal Infinity.

```
Console.WriteLine("10.0 minus NegativeInfinity equals {0}.", (10.0 - Double.NegativeInfinity).ToString());
```

reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx